# Thinking of buying Elder Scrolls Anthology used, will Steam code still work?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I'm thinking of buying Elder Scrolls Anthology used. What I'm wondering is, if the old owner happened to use the Steam code already, will I still be able to use it?

Comment: and fwiw if you have the patience you can wait for a steam sale to pick up any elder scrolls games for deep discounts

Answer (score 7):

Steam keys can only be used once. If the original owner used the product key, you cannot use it.

Comment: Anything with a digital code you should probably not buy used.  It's very unlikely the seller didn't use it.

Comment: @GnomeSlice even worse, quite often you need both the code and the discs to play the game, and if the code was used you now have just a nice set of coasters (and the seller no doubt made copies and continues to use those).